# Length of a line segment between arcs of two circles on line of centers

Tags: geometry, circles

In the following image, I'm trying to solve for $x$ in terms of $r$, $s$, and $\theta$.

[image]

This problem turns up in a non-linear geometry control theory proof I'm writing.  However, sadly, I've forgotten much of trigonometry years ago, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

First, you can use the [Law of Cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) to compute the distance $d$ between the to centers:
$$d^2=r^2+s^2-2rs\cos(\theta_1),$$
where $\theta_1$ is the angle between the radii at the intersection and is equal to $\pi-\theta$.

Next, just note that $x=r+s-d$.

Comment: Thanks for the law of cosines reminder.  I'm still missing why $\theta_1 + \theta = \pi$ however.  I'm including a [picture](http://imgur.com/hWCBC3Y) corresponding to your reasoning for reference.  Is there some theorem regarding this case?  Thanks

Comment: Extend the tangent lines the other way (pointing outward). You should be able to see that.